# In Common Emitter Amplifier Circuit ,Emitter Capacitor effect

Tags: amplifier

I was wondering about the Effect of Emitter Capacitor in Common Emitter Amplifier? It is Suggested that Putting the Bypass Capacitor the output voltage gain is increased but how? As we want more output voltage? I feel The Effect of Capacitor is to reduce the Resistance. Decreasing the resistance ,does it increase the voltage?

Comment: Post a schematic, with parasitic capacitances shown

Answer (score 3):

In a common emitter amplifier with an emitter resistor the collector current and the emitter current are almost identical.

"Gain" is proportional to collector voltage / emitter voltage (by definition) so as Vc = Ic x Rc and as Ve = Ie x Rc and as Ic ~= Ie, Gain = Rc/Re.
 Rc = collectpr resistor and Re = EFFECTIVE emitter resistance. This is the transistor internal Re_internal + theemitter resistor.

If there is no emitter capacitor across the emitter resistor then
 Gain = Rc / (Re + Re_internal).
 If the emitter resistor has a capacitor across it which allows AC to pass with no loss (or not much loss) then
 Gain ~= Rc/Re_internal.

Re external is used to set the DC operating conditions and maximum AC gain occurs when the only emitter resistance = Re_internal.

For a silicon transistor Re_internal "just happens" to be 26/I ohms where I is the emmitter current in mA. This is a basic property of the silicon junction which I'll not go into further here. It makes sense when examined but is not intuitive.

ie if i=1 mA then Re_internal = 26 Ohms.
 If Ie = 4 mA the Re_internal = 26/4 = 6.5 Ohms
 If Ie = 10 mA then Re_internal = 2.6 Ohms

SO **for a fully AC-bypassed Re**  (large enough Ce) :

- Gain = Rc / Re_internal = Rc / (26/mA)
- Following this through you arrive at the "fact" that
  Gain = 38.4 x Vc
  Not many people know that.
  Few people believe it when told :-)

Comment: Thanks for the great info! I have learnt that Re_internal changes with temperature. How to compensate for that, since we are basing our AC gain on Re_internal?

Comment: What does estion mean? Really, Russell, be easy on me, I am not a native speaker :)

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - Sorry - a large amount of text was missing from that answer - Only about half of what I keyed in ended up in the answer! Try again. | You could research "diode temperature compensation" BUT it would be a good idea to describe what you are trying to do in detail and then ask a question. There is very little chance of your requirements being addressed well by the sort of information that can be easily passed between people in comments. [Lots here](http://goo.gl/Fw8Pi) and see my answer [here](http://goo.gl/WOvBe) and [search hits here](http://goo.gl/t4i8c)

Comment: Thanks, of course that is not a question to be answered in comments :) I was asking about the second sentence of yours :) And yes, I've already read your [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/25627/5035), thanks!